# Why do I get a segmentation fault when using "dialog_checklist" from Linux's "dialog.h"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, segmentation-fault, dialog

I wanted to use the `dialog.h` library from the `dialog` Linux package but when I try to make a radiolist (checklist with flag parameter set to 1) it gives me a segmentation fault. I assume it has to do with the list of strings (char**) but I have been unable to find a fix for it.

In this code on line 10 the error occurs:

```
#include <dialog.h>

int main() {
    int distro;
    char dist1[] = "Ubuntu";
    char dist2[] = "Gentoo";
    char *distros[2] = {dist1,dist2};
    init_dialog(stdin, stdout); // start dialog

    distro = dialog_checklist("Select Distro","Select One",0,0,0,2,distros,1);

    end_dialog(); // end dialog
}
```

Incase anyone needs it: [man page for dialog.h](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dialog&sektion=3)

Comment: I got the signature I used in my answer [from here](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man3/dialog_checklist.3.html), but ok, apparently it's not the version you use so I've removed the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I read the documentation wrong, the list was supposed to contain {tag, item, status} for each item.